# Django form fields not rendering when grouping fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using Django 4.0.3 with a bootstrap webinterface.
For layout reasons I want my fields in a ModelForm to be grouped and I'm doing it with:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    template_name = "container/form.html"

    field_groups = [["email", "company"], ["last_name", "first_name"]]
    grouped_fields = []

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ["email", "company", "first_name", "last_name"]

    __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def group_fields(self):
        for group in self._field_groups:
        group_entry = []
        for entry in group:
            group_entry.append(self.fields[entry])

        self.grouped_fields.append(group_entry)
```

in the view I initialize my form and the regroup the fields:

```
def user_form(request):
    form = UserForm()
    form.group_fields()
    render(request, "page.html, {"form", form})
```

The `page.html` looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="form-wrapper">
        {{ form }}
    </div>
</body>
```

and the `form.html` looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
{% for field_group in form.grouped_fields %}
    <div class="row">
    {% for field in field_group %}
        <div class="col">
            <label>{{ field.label }}</label> {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However the rendered fields are displayed as string representations of the field objects:

```
Email <django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0x7f98c00e03a0>
Company <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f98c00e0250>
Last name <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f98c00e0790>
First name <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f98c00e10c0>
```

Whereas a common call renders as expected a form with input fields, but not with the desired layout.

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I also tried to move the call of the `group_fields` method to the form **init** but had no success.
Is there a way to render the fields, that are stored in my `grouped_fields` container correctly?

Comment: Hey, did you ever figured out what was the problem? Curious if you solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe my posted answer will help you with the issue. I ended up writing my own template that is looping through the field_groups

Comment: Thanks! Kind of came up with the solution-ish. OT, you can accept your own answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After quiet a time of trying this and that I ended up writing a wrapper for `ModelForm`, define my `field_groups` there and rendered it in the template.
It is not nice, but it does the trick.

```
<form action="" method="post">
   {% for fieldgroup in form.field_groups %}
        <div class="row fieldgroup">
        {% for fieldname in fieldgroup %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {% if field.name == fieldname %}
                <div class="col pt-2">
                    <label class="form-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```